# Show images in different sections, of the same Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, razor

I have an Azure Blob which has a container with several subfolders in it. In the previous question they answered me how I get one of the subfolders to output its contents without outputting the others. So far so good.

The problem now is this:

I have several sections, for example, DFD, Use Case, Flowcharts and so on.. These are sectioned as you will see in the screenshot. I have to find a way how to output each subfolder under the correct section.

I am using `public ActionResult Index()` which returns `View(blobList)`  (will show the code soon). The problem with this is that it only shows one subcontainer and I have to manually input it.

Is there a way where I can show different images at different section when getting them from the blob?

I tried writing a method which basically gets the URLs from a particular blob according to the subfolder specified, but I do not know how to return the list of String from the Controller to the View.

here are some screenshots and coding I'm using

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUqox.png [e.g in statediagrams there should be the first two images and in Activity Diagram, the remaining pictures]

This is the coding:

**SystemDesign.cs** // Model

public class SystemDesign
{
    public string URL { get; set; }

```
public static SystemDesign returnImageURL(IListBlobItem item)
{

    if (item is CloudBlockBlob)
    {
        var blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
        return new SystemDesign { URL = blob.Uri.ToString() };

    }
    return null;
}
```

}

**SystemDesignModel.cs**

```
public class SystemDesignModel
    {
        public SystemDesignModel() : this(null)
        {
            Files = new List<SystemDesign>();
        }

        public SystemDesignModel(IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> list)
        {
            Files = new List<SystemDesign>();

            foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    SystemDesign test = SystemDesign.returnImageURL(item);
                    Files.Add(test);

                }


        }
        public List<SystemDesign> Files { get; set; }
    }
```

**index.cshtml**

```
<!-- other code hidden from brevity -->
@foreach (var item in Model.Files)
{
    <a href="@item.URL"><img src="@item.URL" height="128" width="128" /></a>
}
```

**SystemDesignController Index()**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // Code until Container reference removed from brevity

            Models.SystemDesignModel blobsListDFD = new Models.SystemDesignModel(storageContainer.ListBlobs("**dfd**", useFlatBlobListing: true));
            return View(blobsListDFD);
        }
```

**This is the method I tried inventing in order to return the list of string URIs but do not know how to pass it to the View from the Controller** In this method I wanted to pass the container name in the Index.cshtml and then according to the parameter, I output those images in the said subfolder

```
public List<string> showBlobs(string blobContainerName)
{
    StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials("swiftdevelopmentstorage", "HqaCkZjdQ8w/DX/fS3wDxU6HXbeqV5EZ1b+UQaKALxaJDrN9JoZZYn8Q0KT6QR4tCrdGQicxE+tKRKScjINW8w==");
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer storageContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("systemdesign");

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    Models.SystemDesignModel blobsListDFD = new Models.SystemDesignModel(storageContainer.ListBlobs("dfd", useFlatBlobListing: true));
    foreach (var item in blobsListDFD.Files)
    {
        list.Add(item.URL.ToString());
    }


    return list;

}
```

Is there anything I can change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is embarrassing but I'm going to answer my own question because I figured out how to fix it.

What I did is I implemented a `_PartialView` which is connected to the method `showBlobs(string containerName)` . The code found in `Index.cshtml` which is the `@foreach` was instead relocated into the Partial View such that it only shows the images from the wanted container due to the parameter passed.

Below I am posting all the re-written code which makes it work. Hope it'll be help to someone

**SystemDesignController.cs** // Changed Index() and _showBlobs()

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
// Other code

[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult _showBlobs(string containerName)
{
    StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(name, key);
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer storageContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(rootContainer);


    Models.SystemDesignModel blobsList = new Models.SystemDesignModel(storageContainer.ListBlobs(containerName, useFlatBlobListing: true));

    return PartialView(blobsList);

}
```

**_showBlobs.cshtml** // Partial View

```
@{
        foreach (var item in Model.Files)
        {
            <a href="@item.URL"><img src="@item.URL" height="128" width="128" /></a>

        }

}
```

**SystemDesignModel.cs** // Model and instance

```
 public partial class SystemDesign
    {
        public string URL { get; set; }


        public SystemDesign() { }

        public SystemDesign (string url, string directory)
        {
            this.URL = url;

        }

        public static SystemDesign returnImageURL(IListBlobItem item)
        {

            if (item is CloudBlockBlob)
            {
                var blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
                return new SystemDesign 
                {   URL = blob.Uri.ToString(),

                };

            }
            return null;
        }

    }   


    // System Design Model 
    public partial class SystemDesignModel
    {
        public SystemDesignModel() : this(null)
        {
            Files = new List<SystemDesign>();
        }

        public SystemDesignModel(IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> list)
        {
            Files = new List<SystemDesign>();

            foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    SystemDesign test = SystemDesign.returnImageURL(item);
                    Files.Add(test);

                }


        }
        public List<SystemDesign> Files { get; set; }
    }
```